# Core i3 running slow, what could be the reason?

Tags: performance, debian, intel-core-i3

I've just built a shiny new i3 system for use as a home server and to host a Minecraft world. The CPU is clocked at 3.1 GHz and I have added 8 GB memory, yet the system is substantially slower than the Atom (clocked at 1.6 GHz) I was using before.

The system is unable to serve files at more than about 200kB/s, takes about ten seconds to format a manual page, and the Minecraft server continuously complains about not being able to advance game time as fast as real time.

Any ideas what might cause such drastic problems? The last time I've seen an effect like this was with uncached memory on an i486. :)

Comment: Just for clarification: is it under the same load as your previous atom-based machine, or is the Minecraft world new?

Comment: Please post the complete setup of the machine, including OS and AntiVirus software and hardware.

Comment: Have you checked BIOS options to make sure that caches are enabled and all relevant options checked as installed relevant Windows software?

Comment: The OS is Debian squeeze, and has not been modified for the mainboard switch.

Comment: BIOS settings are difficult to access as I'm not in front of the machine right now; will post these later.

Comment: I would try to disentangle between memory, harddisk,cpu and network performance by running individual benchmarks such as `ramspeed` (RAM), `hdparm -t` (harddisk) and `iperf` (network).

Comment: Is there any way you can benchmark the system using a LiveCD of some kind?  Tt could potentially be a weird driver issue if you simply copied the system from the old Atom to the new i3 computer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the issue, two misbehaving network cards that leave their level-triggered IRQ asserted.

Comment: Once you confirm this is the answer, please be sure to accept your own answer.